# If a domain is secured with HTTPS, does it become less secure if the URL is typed using HTTP?

Tags: http, https

For example, does the URL `http://www.google.com/` make the URL less safe, even though the default for this domain is with `https`?

Comment: "Safety" just means "data exchanged in the TCP/IP connection is encrypted".  Http and https are "protocols" (for communicating with the domain).  Most websites - including Google - are configured so that typing "http" will redirect the client to "https".  Most browsers will display a visual warning if the connection isn't https.

Comment: This helps, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing a site using `http://` (thus the unprotected unecrypted HTTP protocol) means that at least one unprotected HTTP request is sent to the server (most sites that support https will automatically redirect you to the https version).

This unprotected request can be intercepted by an attacker and thus send you arbitrary data back (malicious JavaScript code, redirect to other sites and so on).

The only exception is if you type `http://www.google.com/` and you are using Chrome browser because Chrome will for addresses on google.com automatically change the entered URL to `https://` before anything is sent on the network.